# Vanilla JS: Slider input / mousemove firing too often -> too many function calls

Tags: javascript, performance

I noticed that sliders firing too often when used with event listeners on input / mousemove.
That is causing unneccessary function calls. A console.log when moving a slider could look like so:

value: 0.01
value: 0.02
value: 0.03
value: 0.03
value: 0.03
value: 0.03
value: 0.04
...

I know about debounce, setInterval etc... but i find it to be not elegant. I'd rather like to have some kind of logic for preventing the execution of the function with the same value over and over again. Like this pseudocode:

```
    document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("input", evt => {

         if (oldValue !== newValue) {

            foo(newValue);   
      
         } else {
      
            break
         }     
   
   
   });
```

But as it turns out, it's not as trivial as it seems on first sight. At least for me. Anyone here could be so kind to help me out?

Comment: Just use the change event?

Comment: The problem is, that changes won't happen in real time then but on mouseup